# What is the purpose of WP_CONTENT_URL?

Tags: plugins, themes, wp-config

While trying to move the wp-content to new folder, there is constant called `WP_CONTENT_URL`.

Why do we need this one? Does `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_CONTENT_URL` needs to be same?

Bcoz there are several websites which can find my wordpress themes and plugins. how do they do that?

I am trying to move move my wp-content folder so added this code in wp-config.php just above `require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );`

`define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . 'server/stuffs');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 'server/stuffs' );`

But it causes ***Internal server error***, when I trying to access my admin page

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/content_url/
the guide may helfull to you to undestood the purpose of it

Comment: Does WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL needs to be same?

Comment: no both are different
WP_CONTENT_DIR = give you path of your directory
where as WP_CONTENT_URL = give you url

Comment: I did the same but it causes 500